# Only thoughts were experienced during practice

Tags: personal-practice, theravada, vipassana

Now no sounds were experienced during meditation only thinking was there.what shall be done here?

Answer (score 1):

If thoughts are experienced, find out who's the experiencer of your thoughts. Be a spectator or witness to your thoughts. Be relaxed, don't treat your thoughts just leave without dabbling with them. Be a mute witness.

Answer (score 0):

from Kaṇṭaka sutta

> .........First higher state of the mind, sounds are a thorn. To one in the second higher state of the mind, thoughts and discursive thoughts are a thorn...

congrats and anumodana on you accomplishment.  Seems to me you are well into first Jhanna.  What is next? If i have accomplished what you have done, would try to let go/not involve with thoughts since it is thorn to second jhanna.

[Kantaka Sutta](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/4Anguttara-Nikaya/Anguttara6/10-dasakanipata/008-akankhavaggo-e.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would say for most, myself included, that it can often be difficult to get to and sometimes maintain the state you describe. I too experience this on a regular basis. Most of my meditations that is to say. Wasn’t always this way. In my opinion, it is progress and not to be concerned about. It’s all just part of the process.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

If mind is attached, concentrated on a certain object well, the other animals lose. One does not hear sounds most and many times, yet far away from right concentration.

> Just as if a person, catching six animals of different ranges, of different habitats, were to bind them with a strong rope. Catching a snake, he would bind it with a strong rope. Catching a crocodile... a bird... a dog... a hyena... a monkey, he would bind it with a strong rope. Binding them all with a strong rope, and tying a knot in the middle, he would set chase to them.
>
> "Then those six animals, of different ranges, of different habitats, would each pull toward its own range & habitat. The snake would pull, thinking, 'I'll go into the anthill.' The crocodile would pull, thinking, 'I'll go into the water.' The bird would pull, thinking, 'I'll fly up into the air.' The dog would pull, thinking, 'I'll go into the village.' The hyena would pull, thinking, 'I'll go into the charnel ground.' The monkey would pull, thinking, 'I'll go into the forest.' And when these six animals became internally exhausted, they would submit, they would surrender, they would come under the sway of whichever among them was the strongest. In the same way, when a monk whose mindfulness immersed in the body is undeveloped & unpursued, the eye pulls toward pleasing forms, while unpleasing forms are repellent. The ear pulls toward pleasing sounds... The nose pulls toward pleasing aromas... The tongue pulls toward pleasing flavors... The body pulls toward pleasing tactile sensations... The intellect pulls toward pleasing ideas, while unpleasing ideas are repellent. This, monks, is lack of restraint.
>
> "And what is restraint?...[The Six Animals](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.206.than_en.html#six)

"Just" be mind"full"! Observe the animals within the frames of references.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score 0):

What should be done is to continue with the meditation work diligently and work on understanding the instubstantiality of questioning experiences during meditation, which are based on judging and  comparing and finds its roots in doubt.
All meditation effords will be fruitious when done with the right efford and intention and will naturally evolve in subtler states. Sole volition as the driving force and understanding of creation of karma  will be enough to progress.
Be well.